# How to make a condition test correspond to subcolumns of an ODM decision table?

Tags: jrules, ibm-odm

I'm using ODM 8.5 (the successor to JRules), and I'm mimicking the steps described in IBM's tutorial - [Editing Decision Tables](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dmanager/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wodm.dserver.rules.tutorials/tut_designer_topics/tut_editdt_crtminagedt_lsn.html); however, I can't generate a legal test.  In the tutorial, they create the following test:

```
the customer's age of the 'current rental agreement' is at least <min> and less than <max>
```

If I use Eclipse's completion feature () to generate legal completions for the table I want to create, I can't generate `<min>` or `<max>`, but I can generate `<a string>`.  However, this generates the following warning, and does not create subcolumns.

[image]

I don't know what the warning is trying to tell me (and I resent getting a warning when I am using a suggested replacement).  ("Lexicographically greater than" is a function I've defined that takes two string arguments; however, changing to a predefined function like "contains", makes no difference.)  If I manually change the occurrences of `<a string>` to `<min>` and `<max>`, I get an error:

[image]

How can I make my decision table act like the one in the tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is how to use the `<min>` and `<max>` terms instead of `<a string>`.  This is dependent on the verbalization of the method created in the BOM, as described in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22996144/how-to-define-a-function-for-use-in-an-odm-decision-table-w-o-changing-the-xom?rq=1).  In summary, you need to create a method with a verbalization like:

```
{0} is in the range {1,min} to {2,max}
```

to get the words "min" and "max" to appear.

Then, when you edit the Condition Column of your decision table, you create a Test something like:

```
the modified ep code of 'the work assignment input' 
is in the range <min> to <max>
```

At this point, the Expression Placeholders text box will be empty.  Click `OK` in the Condition Column dialog and the appropriate `min` and `max` subcolumns will be produced in the table.  Thereafter, editing the Condition Column will include entries in the Expression Placeholders text box, that can be edited via the Sub-column Title text box.

[image]